# phpserialize : a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cakephp

I am converting a website from Cakephp to django and I am having problem using a function unserialize from php.

```
$details = unserialize(temp);
```

I converted this into python as ->

```
from phpserialize import *
details = loads(temp)
```

I am getting this error

`a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

My data contains mostly Japanese character and look like this ->

```
a:15:{
  s:9:"CandidateA";a:9:{
    s:4:"mail";s:21:"somemail@gmail.com";
    s:4:"name";s:22:"name1";
    s:7:"something1";s:19:"something";
    s:6:"mobile";s:13:"12345678";
    s:7:"zipcode";s:8:"123456";
    s:9:"address_1";s:18:"address1";
    s:9:"address_2";s:5:"0987659";
    s:15:"something2";s:9:"something3";
    s:6:"street";s:24:"address2";
  }
   s:6:"CandidateB";a:9:{
    s:4:"mail";s:21:"somemail@gmail.com";
    s:4:"name";s:22:"name1";
    s:7:"something1";s:19:"something";
    s:6:"mobile";s:13:"12345678";
    s:7:"zipcode";s:8:"123456";
    s:9:"address_1";s:18:"address1";
    s:9:"address_2";s:5:"0987659";
    s:15:"something2";s:9:"something3";
    s:6:"street";s:24:"address2";
  }
  ----
  ----
  ----
  ----
  ----


}
```

`----` means that there are more repetition.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of temp seems to be string which means it contains utf-8 character.
But you need a byte-like object.

To convert a string into a byte-like object you need to encode it.

```
>>> temp='whatever'
>>> print(temp)
whatever
>>> type(temp)
<class 'str'>

>>> btemp = temp.encode('utf-16')
>>> print(btemp)
b'\xff\xfew\x00h\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00'
>>> type(btemp)
<class 'bytes'>
```

You need to look for what kind of encoding you will need for japanese characters.